# Resume Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have 2 `Activity` A and B, A calls B so, I want to `Resume` parent `Activity` (A) when B calls `finish()` on its `Activity`. Any advice will be useful.

**UPDATE:** 
Maybe I should mention that I use fragments, each Activity has its own fragment, I call finish() from fragment hosted inside B activity and I expect to receive Resume on fragment belongs to A.

Comment: It will be automatically resumed if you haven't finished the parent activity while starting new one. Do you have any specific use case?

Comment: I didn't finish the parent activity, A calls B, then B calls finish.

Comment: In this case `onResume` of A will be called automatically. No need to do anything. Just override this method in A.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I have updated my post, please take a look..

Comment: Fragments onResume won't be called automatically. I am sure your activity `onResume` is being called. Why don't you call your fragments onResume manually from there.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Activity B`, `Activity A` will go to background. Unless you finish `Activity A` while starting `Activity B`, it will automatically resume when `Activity B` finishes.

If you are calling this,

```
startActivity(ActivityB.class, this);
finish();
```

Just remove the `finish()`. It should work as expected.

Comment: Well, you I have to finish (A)? What about activity life-cycle? Activity will pause if it went to background, then It must be resume! Am I missed something with understanding life-cycle?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly finish it. Android is smart enough to handle this and it will manage this for you

Comment: Can you post code where you start and finish activities